# The url gets corrupted when I go to post detail

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, uri, codeigniter-4

**When I go to detail, I overwrite the menu links and get an error.**

**route**

```
 $routes->group('(en|tr)', ['namespace' => 'App\Controllers\Frontend'], function ($routes) {
    $routes->get('announcement-detail/(:any)', 'Home::announcementDetail/$1/$2');
```

**detail link**

```
<a href="announcement-detail/<?= $key['yazi_id']; ?>"
                                           class="btn btn-small btn-main btn-round-full">
```

**url error**

[image]

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: When I try to reach another address from the menu while on my detail page `localhost/proje/tr/announcement-detail/contact` Announcement detail stays fixed in the url and adds it. What i want `localhost/proje/tr/contact`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to configure your url like this

```
 <a href="<?= base_url('announcement-detail') ?>/<?= $key['yazi_id']; ?>">
```